# Make an EX4 indicator available to test only some days

Tags: mql4

I developped a MQL4 indicator and have to make it available and downloadable on the website only for 10 days, the time for the user 
to try and test it and then decide to get it or not.
My problem is how to make this indicator available only 10 days when the user downloads it.
Any help or any suggestion will be very helpfull.

Comment: ask at MQL5.com directly, they do not have service desk now but reply quite fast if you create a thread on the forum. Read their policy first. Most likely you will have to do that via settings when uploading the indicator, putting any restrictions inside the code or use of DLL is prohibited. So consult with them and let them do their job, this is not an MQL4 question. If selling outside of MQL5.com - you will have to compile an indicator when someone downloads it (or compile 1 version per day) and keep track of HWID of users who downloaded it in your DB.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It was clear and logic. I prefer to deal with the website I mentioned in my topic. So I will try to use "FileOpen()" function with some encryption of data I will put Inside the txt or csv file.

Comment: You probably know that indicators cannot call WebRequest function, right? So you will need wininet.dll to make a web request. Another question is how you would detect hardware ID, probably better to ask at C++ section. Regarding time - it is ok to work forever in tester mode? if not, you will need to find GMT time (either via wininet.dll or with some other dlls

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I'm back first of all to thank you for your answers and then to inform you of the agreement of the decision-makers, of my company, about the way to do for the indicators and for the EAs.
The technical choice of the IT architecture service has been adopted and the company will continue to use, for 2019 and 2020, files to detect the modes Demo and Real Account. So there will be, for now neither dll nor WebRequest.